# Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jws/WebService in Java 11

Tags: java, cxf, jax-ws, cxf-client

In my cxf webservice invocation while I set the JaxWsProxyFactoryBean service class, I get a fatal error whose trace I have given below. I am migrating my code from java 8 to java 11.

I have set all the required library jars,cxf bundle and jax-ws jars at my build path but still I am unable to resolve the error.
Here is my code:

```
        APIWS _stub = null;
        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean fac = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        
        fac.setAddress(API_WS_URL);
        fac.setServiceClass(APIWS.class);

        _stub = (APIWS) fac.create();
        Client c = ClientProxy.getClient(_stub);
        HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit)c.getConduit();
        HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
        policy.setConnectionTimeout(0);
        policy.setReceiveTimeout(0);
        http.setClient(policy);

        c.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
        c.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
        ApiWS.aboutCall(_stub);
        List<String> output = ApiWS.invokeLiqApiWebService(_stub, transformedQueue);
        outputFileList.addAll(output);
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jws/WebService
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsImplementorInfo.initialize(JaxWsImplementorInfo.java:273)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsImplementorInfo.<init>(JaxWsImplementorInfo.java:60)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientFactoryBean.setServiceClass(JaxWsClientFactoryBean.java:43)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.setServiceClass(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:224)
at com.qnb.ib.loaniq.inbound.interfaces.process.LIQProcess.callLiqAPI(LIQProcess.java:331)
at com.qnb.ib.loaniq.inbound.interfaces.process.LIQProcess.process(LIQProcess.java:154)
at com.qnb.ib.loaniq.inbound.interfaces.process.LIQJobManager.processJob(LIQJobManager.java:106)
at com.qnb.ib.loaniq.inbound.interfaces.process.LIQJobManager.main(LIQJobManager.java:132)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jws.WebService
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 8 more
```

Need help resolving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Anything in javax you need to bring yourself now.

Comment: I have included the jar javax.jws-api-1.1.jar with other relevent javax jars and it resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

These are the jars I have added in my build path to resolve the issue with calling the Web Services.

- FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar
- gmbal-api-only-3.1.0-b001.jar
  -ha-api-3.1.9.jar
- istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar
- javax.activation-1.2.0.jar
- javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
- javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar
- javax.jws-api-1.1.jar
- javax.xml.soap-api-1.4.0.jar
- jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
- jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar
- jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar
- jaxws-ri-2.3.1.pom
- jaxws-rt-2.3.1.jar
- management-api-3.0.0-b012.jar
- mimepull-1.9.10.jar
- policy-2.7.5.jar
- saaj-impl-1.5.0.jar stax2-api-4.1.jar
- stax-ex-1.8.jar
- streambuffer-1.5.6.jar
  -txw2-2.3.1.jar
- woodstox-core-5.1.0.jar

Hope this helps those who are facing similar issue in java 11

Comment: You should consider using a dependency manager, like Maven.

Comment: My production is not using maven and for the migration they wish to keep it similar and hence I am using old ways.

Comment: If so this is most likely a rather old application, with rather old jar files, and "they" should strongly consider using this opportunity to update to newest versions and run security checks and upgrade frameworks like log4j.  You will most likely not get a similiar opportunity to do so for the foreseable future.